# How to fix this block matrix in a way that the dotted line appears inside the matrix?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nicematrix

I would like to fix this next block matrix in a way that the dotted line appears inside the matrix: [image: Block Matrix using nicematrix]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\NewDocumentCommand{\MyMatrixA}{m}
  {
    \begin{pNiceMatrix}
    1 & 0  & \Block{2-2}<\Large>{A_{#1}} &  \\
    1 & 0  &                            & \\
    1 &  0     & 1  & 0 \\
    \CodeAfter 
        \tikz \draw [dotted] (1-|3) -- (4-|3) 
                             (1-|5) -- (4-|5) 
                             (1-|3) -- (1-|5) 
                (3-|3) -- (3 -|5);
    \end{pNiceMatrix}
  }

\begin{document}

$\MyMatrixA{i}$

\end{document}
```

I tried changing  `(3-|3) -- (3 -|5)` to   `(3-|3) -- (3 -|4.5)` , but apparently it only accepts integer numbers.

THANKS

Comment: Ok. Adding an `extra-margin` command in  `\begin{pNiceMatrix}[extra-margin=6pt]` suffices...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\NewDocumentCommand{\MyMatrixA}{m}
  {%
\begin{pNiceMatrix}
    1 & 0  & \Block{2-2}<\Large>{A_{#1}}    &   &   \\
    1 & 0  &                                &   &   \\
    1 & 0  & 1                              & 0 &   \\
  \CodeAfter 
         \tikz \draw [dotted] (row-1-|col-3) -- (row-1-|col-5)  -- (row-3-|col-5) -- (row-3-|col-3) ; 
         \tikz \draw [dotted] (row-1-|col-3) -- (row-4-|col-3); 
 \end{pNiceMatrix}
  }

\begin{document}

$\MyMatrixA{i}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Remark: In recent version of `nicematrix`, you can use the syntax `(i-|j)` instead of `(row-i-|-col-j)`...